# Uniform and product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, infinite-product

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb N}$ and the two metrics:

$$d(x,y)=\sum^{\infty}2^{-i}\min(1,|x_i-y_i|)$$ and $$d'(x,y)=\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\min(1,|x_i-y_i|).$$

If $O$ is $d$-open, is it $d'$-open? I tried to prove that $d\geq d'$, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to proceed.

Comment: $\mathbb R^\infty$ is not a good notation. You mean $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ I think.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: $d$ metrizes pointwise convergence, while $d’$ metrizes uniform convergence. So there are strictly less “many” convergent sequences for $d’$ than for $d$. So $d$-open subsets are $d‘$-open, and the converse isn’t true.

Comment: Within metric spaces, it is "easier" or "more natural" (at least to me) to consider closed sets rather than open sets. This is beacause the convergent sequences give a direct caracterization of the closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have $d \le d^\prime$, which implies that any open ball $B_{d^\prime}(a,r)$ is included in $B_d(a,r)$.

With that, you can prove that any $d$-open is a $d^\prime$-open.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do the steps thanks.